# Filtering a Scala Set from Java

Tags: java, scala

I want to filter a scala set from java, below is my code.

```
scala.collection.immutable.Set<Member> set = cluster.state().members();
                    Function1<Member, UniqueAddress> filter = new AbstractFunction1<Member, UniqueAddress>(){
                        public UniqueAddress apply(Member member){
                            return member.uniqueAddress();
                        }
                    };

                    scala.collection.immutable.Set<UniqueAddress> set1 = set.filter(filter);
```

But it has error with

> The method filter(Function1 < Member,Object>) in the type
>   TraversableLike < Member,Traversable < Member>> is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Function1 < Member,UniqueAddress>)

How can I fix this?

Comment: shouldn't `filter` have type `Function1<Member, Boolean>`?

Comment: What `Member` you want to filter out?

Comment: Based on your `Function1` definition, it seems you want to use the `map` method and not `filter`. `map` is used to transform the objects in your set, `filter` to filter out elements.

Comment: I would convert (wrap) it is a Java Set and then just apply a Java lambda on that to do the filtering. This saves you some Java/Scala interoperability issues like this. Only from Scala 2.12 you can use Scala lambdas in Java and vise versa.

Comment: I should use map in my case. I want to get a new Set<UniqueAddress> from Set<Member>.

Answer (score 1):

After filtering a `Set<Member>`, you'll get a `Set<Member>`, not a `Set<UniqueAddress>`. Do you mean `map`? At any rate, given how Scala collections use implicits, I really wouldn't recommend working with them from Java, except by either

1. converting them to Java collections using `JavaConversions` first (but of course, this doesn't give you equivalents to `map`/`filter`/etc.), or
2. writing a wrapper specifically for using them from Java.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I should use map in my case. Based on your suggestions, I will convert scala set to java set.